# Parse, saveAll failing after two httpRequests (Cloud Code job)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I am running a job that does the following

- httpRequest
- - processing
- - - httpRequest to different server using some of the processed data
- - - - more processing, extending a Parse.Object model and then
- - - - - saveAll

At one point I was doing only one httpRequest that did the saveAll and it worked.

After I added the second httpRequest, the saveAll stopped working

I've read some anecdotal things about "2 queries / httpRequests per job/function" and then I've read some other anecdotal things about Promises, and some anecdotal things about chaining promises but at this point I am lost

so I've rewritten this job to use Promises but I am still getting an error in the saveAll method

```
Parse.Cloud.job("myJob", function(request, status) {

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.website.com/api/method",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(function(httpResponse)
    /*,success: function(httpResponse)*/
    {

        var symbols = httpResponse.data["symbols"];

        var tickerNames = new Array();

        symbols.forEach(function(obj) {

            tickerNames.push(obj.symbol);
            //maybe do a before save method to check if it already exists               

        });

        return tickerNames;
    }).then(function(tickerNames) {

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api.secondsite.org/api/" + tickerNames.join(","),
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer ACCESSTOKEN",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
        /*,
                            success: function(httpResponse) {*/
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {

            var serverObjects = new Array();

            var objectArray = httpResponse.data["quotes"]["quote"];
            objectArray.forEach(function(obj) {

                var SocialPicks = Parse.Object.extend("SocialPicks");
                var newPick = new SocialPicks();
                newPick.set("symbol", obj.symbol);
                newPick.set("title", obj.description);
                newPick.set("changePercent", obj.change_percentage);
                newPick.set("volume", obj.volume);
                newPick.set("avgVolume", obj.average_volume);

                //newPick.save();

                serverObjects.push(newPick);

            });

            //console.log(serverObjects[0].symbol);

            var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

            promise = promise.then(function(){
                return Parse.Object.saveAll(serverObjects)
                .then(function(list) {

                    console.log("saveAll success");
                    status.success("success");

                }, function(error) {
                    console.log("saveAll error");
                    status.error("not successful saving");
                });
            })

            return promise;

        },
        /*error: function(error) {*/
        function(httpResponse) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            status.error("not successful network call");
        }
    );

});

  });
```

this always fails with `status.error("not successful saving");` , whether I use promises or a sequential version of this method without promises

at this point I'm not sure if I have hit a limitation of parse, or if I am using promises incorrectly, or both, or other

so, if anyone has experience doing subsequent httpRequests in Cloud Code and then writing the objects, insight would be helpful

Comment: The actual code reduced to  the minimal failing case would help a lot.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum from my experience using the javascript tag, I know that community here loves seeing code even where it isn't necessary. This is more about a limitation with Parse that someone might have experience with

Comment: That's great, but my experience with the promises tag is that it's incredibly hard to debug promises code without seeing what the OP attempted - and very little is accomplished by just showing how to do this (thenable chaining (running in sequence), aggregation (.all) and so on).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum okay, I'll consider adding my function

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum updated with code

Comment: `}).then(function(tickerNames) {

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({` you're missing a `return` here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum okay I changed it to `.then(function(tickerNames) {

return    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({`  same error `not successful saving`

Comment: `.then(function(tickerNames)` does not seem to be chained to a promise. Am I missing something?

Comment: It would help to see the first version of the code - before you  added the second httpRequest.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich how would you rewrite it so that it was chained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was erroring due to a type error from one of the API servers.

It was providing an int and my model was looking for a string at that variable

After stepping away from the problem a while, I realized I wasn't printing the actual error that the method was trying to tell me about. Printed it, saw the problem in the console, fixed the problem.

quot erot demonstratum

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's my simplification of the code.

I've done three main mods :

- Used `array.map()` in two places to build `tickerNames` and `serverObjects`.
- Unnested the `serverObjects`/`saveall()` routine to put it in the outer promise chain.
- Purged the unnecessary `Parse.Promise.as()`

```
Parse.Cloud.job("myJob", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.website.com/api/method',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var tickerNames = httpResponse.data.symbols.map(function(obj) {
            return obj.symbol;
            //maybe do a before save method to check if it already exists
        });
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.secondsite.org/api/' + tickerNames.join(),
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESSTOKEN',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var serverObjects = httpResponse.data.quotes.quote.map(function(obj) {
            var SocialPicks = Parse.Object.extend("SocialPicks");
            var newPick = new SocialPicks();
            newPick.set('symbol', obj.symbol);
            newPick.set('title', obj.description);
            newPick.set('changePercent', obj.change_percentage);
            newPick.set('volume', obj.volume);
            newPick.set('avgVolume', obj.average_volume);
            return newPick;
        });
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(serverObjects).then(function(list) {
            console.log('saveAll success');
            status.success('success');
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('saveAll error: ' + error.message);
            status.error('not successful saving');
        });
    }, function(httpResponse) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error.message);
        status.error('not successful network call');
    });
});
```

Please note that this doesn't solve the reported bug, which we now know lies elsewhere, but may be helpful in other ways.

Comment: thanks, both you guys will likely get half the bounty

Comment: @CQM, I'm not worried about the bounty, it's no big deal. Besides, you solved the issue yourself in the end.